# How to resolve SSL Handshake failure between Android app and Dropwizard server

Tags: android, ssl, dropwizard

I am trying to make an HTTP request from an Android app to a Dropwizard server that I have created, and am seeing an SSL handshake failure due to **WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER**.  How do I make them work together?

As far as SSL or other authentication goes, I am using default technologies for both Dropwizard and Android--haven't configured anything for either.  I tried setting different protocols on the server with JVM arguments

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
```

But that didn't seem to make any difference.  Since I haven't set anything, I don't know what each side is using by default.

This is how I am making the connection inside my app:

```
 private class ScanRetreiver extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String resultString = null;
        try {
            //send GET request to REST API for list of items
            URL url = new URL(args[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                resultString = convertStreamToString(in);
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();

                //display items--this means generating an arbitrary list of elements.  should be fun
                //optionally, elements can be expandable
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultString;
    }
```

I see the Exception at the line where I try to call `getInputStream` on the `urlConnection`.

This is the error message that I see on the App side of things:

```
 W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
 W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:302)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:1480)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:1424)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:1368)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:219)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:142)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:104)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:325)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:470)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:416)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:244)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
 W/System.err:     at com.example.myfirstapp.ScanResultActivity$ScanRetreiver.doInBackground(ScanResultActivity.java:55)
 W/System.err:     at com.example.myfirstapp.ScanResultActivity$ScanRetreiver.doInBackground(ScanResultActivity.java:45)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x73e73f3908: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242 0x73f51bfecf:0x00000000)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:231)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: test the server with https://testssl.sh/ and check which protocols it supports. If it is a public server you can also use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/.

Comment: Just used that, and according to testsslh.sh, my server "doesn't seem to be a TSL/SSL enabled server".  So, I guess it's not using SSL, but my Android app is by default.  So now I either need to find a way to disable it in my app (temporarily, for test purposes) or go ahead and figure out how to enable it on my server in a way that's complementary.

Comment: Another note: here is the [configuration reference for the HTTPS handling](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.11/docs/manual/configuration.html#https). Also refer to the sample: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/ca2c9f164081c48181697c453676d92e7b0c36b0/dropwizard-example/example.yml#L33-L36